# CSS - How to add a second gradient to make this button half transparent?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, gradient, transparent

I have these two buttons:

[image: button]

And i want to achive this effect:

[image: buttons]

Or just make the "button 2" half transparent (fade out effect) on the left side. 
I think this can be achived with a second gradient that is transparent.

**EDIT:** The "button 1" and the "button 2" are parts of a form.

Here is my CSS:

```
.myButton {

border: none;
margin-right:0; 
padding-right:0; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #273b73;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #273b73;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #273b73;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #595cb3), color-stop(1, #494099));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #595cb3 5%, #494099 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #595cb3 5%, #494099 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #595cb3 5%, #494099 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #595cb3 5%, #494099 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #595cb3 5%, #494099 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#595cb3', endColorstr='#494099',GradientType=0);
background-color:#595cb3;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
border-bottom-left-radius:8px;  -moz-border-top-left-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
border-top-left-radius:8px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:15px 60px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #3e5b8a;
}
.myButton:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #494099), color-stop(1, #595cb3));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #494099 5%, #595cb3 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #494099 5%, #595cb3 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #494099 5%, #595cb3 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #494099 5%, #595cb3 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #494099 5%, #595cb3 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#494099', endColorstr='#595cb3',GradientType=0);
background-color:#494099;
}



.myButton2 {
border: none;
margin-left:-20px; padding-left:0; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #273b73;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #273b73;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #273b73;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #5986b3), color-stop(1, #406799));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #5986b3 5%, #406799 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5986b3 5%, #406799 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #5986b3 5%, #406799 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #5986b3 5%, #406799 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #5986b3 5%, #406799 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5986b3', endColorstr='#406799',GradientType=0);
background-color:#5986b3;
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
border-bottom-right-radius:8px; -moz-border-top-right-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
border-top-right-radius:8px;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:15px 20px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #3e5b8a;
}
.myButton2:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #406799), color-stop(1, #5986b3));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #406799 5%, #5986b3 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #406799 5%, #5986b3 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #406799 5%, #5986b3 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #406799 5%, #5986b3 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #406799 5%, #5986b3 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#406799', endColorstr='#5986b3',GradientType=0);
background-color:#406799;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use CSS gradients you could achieve that by using something like this:

```
button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 105px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
.one{
        background-color: #4E4EA8;
}
.two{
    background: #2f36ef; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #2f36ef 0%, #2f36ef 0%, #4e4ea8 0%, #4e4ea8 5%, #557cb7 9%, #557cb7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#2f36ef), color-stop(0%,#2f36ef), color-stop(0%,#4e4ea8), color-stop(5%,#4e4ea8), color-stop(9%,#557cb7), color-stop(100%,#557cb7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #2f36ef 0%,#2f36ef 0%,#4e4ea8 0%,#4e4ea8 5%,#557cb7 9%,#557cb7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #2f36ef 0%,#2f36ef 0%,#4e4ea8 0%,#4e4ea8 5%,#557cb7 9%,#557cb7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #2f36ef 0%,#2f36ef 0%,#4e4ea8 0%,#4e4ea8 5%,#557cb7 9%,#557cb7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #2f36ef 0%,#2f36ef 0%,#4e4ea8 0%,#4e4ea8 5%,#557cb7 9%,#557cb7 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2f36ef', endColorstr='#557cb7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */


}
```

This is the example I just created:

http://jsfiddle.net/ncrd9y66/1/

I simply used http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to pick out colours from your example image to use in the generator and copied these into the example. Have a play with the values yourself to get the desired effect. here is mine for reference: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#2f36ef+0,2f36ef+0,4e4ea8+0,4e4ea8+5,557cb7+9,557cb7+100;Custom

(NOTE: these are not exactly the same colours you might be using i picked them out using PS quickly as an example of how you could achieve this effect.)

Comment: Well, it is nicely done, thanks for that :) but i'm still having some problems because as you can see in my css i'm using hover selectors, so when i hover it highlights only part of the button and that makes it ugly.

Comment: Ah, ok. What is your desired hover effect?

Comment: To highlight correctly the button (all the purple colored part for button 1) (all the blue colored part for button 2)

Comment: you could fake it by changing the colour of the hovered button and also change the gradient on its sibling. What colour do you want to change it to on hover? I can mock up the example.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but i'm afraid it won't look very good, it will appear as the button's width is changing, but you can try if you want. You can see the colors under my CSS' hover selectors.

Comment: Example with both buttons with hover states: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/ncrd9y66/4/

Comment: oh, it doesn't look ugly, well I can't say anything, you have done it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the filter blur.. Try it and put the pixels size appropriate for your button.

Example:

```
.myButton2 {
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
   -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
     -o-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Could you also do a demonstration on jsfiddle?

Comment: let me know if you got it. If not I will codify for you